# How to enter a DispatchGroup in a firebase firestore callback

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function where I want to play an animation until the fetching of my data is complete.  I have this variable "loadFetchDone" to indicate that. I need to use snapshotListener when I fetch my data from firebase.

```
    func getLoads(completion: @escaping () -> ()){
    
    bookedLoadsListener = db.collectionGroup("allLoads").whereField("cv", isEqualTo: 1).whereField("status", isEqualTo: "Booked").order(by: "DateBooked", descending: false).addSnapshotListener{ (snapshot, err) in
        
        if err != nil{print("Error getting docs in TruckTrackingView.swift: \(err)")}
        

        loadFetchDone = false
    
        loads = []
        let lGroup = DispatchGroup()
        
    
        
        for load in snapshot?.documents ?? []{

                lGroup.enter()
                
                        ...

                        lGroup.leave()
               
                   
                }
            }
        }
        lGroup.notify(queue: .main){
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

I use this function to get the loads. Once it completes, I set loadFetchDone to true which then stops the loading animation.This is how I call the function

```
        .onAppear(){
        
            globalGroup.enter()
            getLoads {
                globalGroup.leave()
            }
        globalGroup.notify(queue: .main){
                loadFetchDone = true
            }
    
    }
```

If this was a normal getDocuments call, then there wouldn't be a problem but since I am using snapshotListeners, if a change in the document is made, The globalGroup is never entered. This then results in the EXC BAD INSTRUCTION since I leave the group without ever entering it. I have tried entering the group inside the snapshotListener but It never notifies the globalGroup.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using Dispatch groups? They're useful for coordinating multiple async tasks but if you're just grabbing documents from Firestore then there is certainly no need for it.

Comment: @bxod Yes inside the firestore fetch I fetch other mulitple async tasks. Many of them rely on the previous async task.

Comment: Then simply move the dispatch logic out of the view's lifecycle and into the database return, which is how you should handle it anyway IMO. Do all of your entering and exiting within the Firestore return closure.

Comment: But if for some reason you want to keep it this way then in your completion handler, you can specify if the return is get-document or via snapshot listener and only leave the global group on get-document returns. I'm not a fan of this solution but it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you @boxd. First solution solved my problem. I was overthinking it too much. No reason to use DispatchGroup on the outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then simply move the dispatch logic out of the view's lifecycle and into the database return, which is how you should handle it anyway IMO. Do all of your entering and exiting within the Firestore return closure.